# Discord.py count reactions on a message

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm doing a bot discord and I'd like my bot to count the number of reactions to a message before deleting him

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == 614467771866021944:
        if payload.emoji.name == "":
            # if number of reactions > 4:
            # delete the message
```

Comment: Are you looking for 4 times that reaction has been used, 4 reactions total, or 4 unique reactions?

Comment: 5 reactions ""

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the ids in the payload to get the `Message` object of the message and then check the `count` attribute of the appropriate `Reaction` from `Message.reactions`:

```
from discord.utils import get

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == 614467771866021944:
        if payload.emoji.name == "":
            channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            reaction = get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)
            if reaction and reaction.count > 4:
                await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 3):

### How Do I Get a Custom Emoji Count in Discord.py?

Patrick Haugh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58734862/2407742) works for native emojis, but I wanted to add an additional answer to explain getting the `count` attribute for custom emojis since Discord.py defines these attributes differently. The solution itself is easily applies and you can skip to the solution example below if you don't want to read the explanation.

The `emoji` attribute for custom emoji reactions contains a nested set of attributes instead of the single value that native emojis have. Say there is a reaction using a custom emoji named `kirby`. If you were to print `message.reactions`, it would output something like this (assuming you have already appropriately defined `message`):

`[<Reaction emoji='' me=True count=1>, <Reaction emoji=<Emoji id=900000000123456789 name='kirby' animated=False managed=False> me=False count=1>]`

The first reaction has the emoji itself as the attribute `emoji`.
So when you call `get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)` it is just passing the values like so: `get(message.reactions, emoji='')`

Now look at the `emoji` attribute for the custom emoji called `kirby`. Instead of using the emoji as the value here, you will see four attributes nested as the value for the `emoji` attribute. The attributes are `id`, `name`, `animated`, `managed`. Your custom emoji only exists on your server. That means you can't simply paste the emoji into your bot's code the way you can do with native emojis.

You also can't pass the `name` value alone as `payload.emoji.name` will do. Passing `emoji='kirby` in the `get()` utility will cause it to return `None` because it will not be able to match `kirby` in the `emoji` attribute.

> If nothing is found that matches the attributes passed, then None is
> returned.[1](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)

### Solution

The simplest way I've found is to drop the `.name` attribute and just pass `payload.emoji` as your value. Discord.py seems to prefer working with this name:id format for custom emojis. In this example, `get()` will match the `emoji` attribute to a string of nested values `<kirby:900000000123456789>`

Now the `get()` utility will be able to match and return the reaction which includes the `count` attribute you are looking to work with. This example assumes you have already defined `message`:

```
  if payload.emoji.name == 'kirby':
      # payload.emoji will be defined as <kirby:900000000123456789>
      reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji)
      # Now you can get reaction.count for the custom emoji!
      print(f'The reaction count for this custom emoji is: {reaction.count}.')
```