# How do I check the reaction count for a certain message in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to count how many reactions are in a specific message.
Here is the code that I have at the moment, I got it from [Discord.py count reactions on a message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734452/discord-py-count-reactions-on-a-message):

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  if payload.emoji.name == "✊":
      message = 874588154143866890
      reaction = get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)
      if reaction and reaction.count >=0:
          await message.delete()
```

When I test it out I get an error saying:

> name 'get' is not defined

Comment: You link to a different SO article out of which you took part of the answer code, deleting most of the essential code from it. Aside from that it's not really clear what you want to achieve... You seem to want to do 3 different things at the same time, none of them correctly. Do you want to: 1) delete the msg when a certain reaction is added to it 2) count amount of reactions of a certain type 3) count the total amount of reactions?

Comment: The answer you linked has an `import` at the top that you removed