# How do I count reactions on a message in discord py?

Tags: python, pip, discord, discord.py

I'm currently working on a discord bot and I made a command that creates a poll. Now I want the bot to count the reactions and edit the message based on the amount of reactions (If there are more ✅ or more ❌ reactions). I read the API reference and multiple websites, but I couldn't find anything that helps me.

Here is the code I use:

```
    @commands.command(name="poll")
    async def poll(self,ctx: commands.Context,arg1, arg2):
        arg3 = int(arg2)/3600
        embed = discord.Embed(title="NEW POLL", description=f"{arg1} \nPoll lasts for: {round(arg3, 2)}h")
        embed2 = discord.Embed(title="POLL OVER", description="The answer is `yes`(✅)!")
        embed3 = discord.Embed(title="POLL OVER", description="The answer is `no` (❌)!")
        embed4 = discord.Embed(title="POLL OVER", description="It's a tie!")
        message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await message.add_reaction("✅")
        await message.add_reaction("❌")
        time.sleep(int(arg2))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734452/discord-py-count-reactions-on-a-message

Answer (score 1):

This should work!

```py
from discord.utils import get

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(ctx):
    if ctx.channel_id == channelidhere:
        if ctx.emoji.name == "✅":
            channel = client.get_channel(chanelidhere)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(ctx.message_id)
            reaction = get(message.reactions, emoji=ctx.emoji.name)
            COUNT = reaction.count
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how do I add it to the command, so that it's not a new event, but a part of the command. Is that even possible in python?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
most_voted = max(message.reactions, key=lambda r: r.count)
```

Then use `most_voted.emoji` and `most_voted.count-1` (-1 to subtract bot's self reaction) to get the Emoji and Count for that emoji, respectively.